# Add Missing Babel DevDependency

Tags: reactjs

One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message

i have tried by adding this :-
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^1.0.0" // Replace with the appropriate version
}
in the jason file.after that i have installed it.But localhost page is loading..

Comment: This warning is most-likely not related to any issue you have with localhost loading